How categorize instances of a column?
How to write a Teradata query that does this:
The first instance where a Project_Type is A or B for a distinct Project_Num, set the value in RN to 1. Set all other values to NULL. If you come across other instances where the Project_Type is A or B for the same Project_Num, still set the value in RN to NULL. Set RN to 2 if Project_Type is E. If a distinct Project_Num has some combination of Project_Type A, B, and E then set RN equal to 2 the first instance of E and set the RN to NULL for all other values.
Table:
Project_Num          Project_Type      Project_Date                 
100                  A                
100                  B
100                  C
100                  A
100                  E
200                  A
200                  B
200                  C
200                  A
200                  E

Desired Result:
MSN               Project Type         RN  
100               A                    1           
100               B                    NULL   
100               C                    NULL    
100               A                    NULL      
100               E                    NULL      
200               A                    NULL  
200               D                    NULL
200               E                    2 
200               A                    NULL 
200               E                    NULL
300               E                    2
300               E                    NULL
300               F                    NULL 


I'm really struggling to understand your question.  For starters, how are you determining the "first" row for a project_num?

Also your "desired result" does not seem consistent.
